# Duality of diagram categories

Tags: category-theory

Fixed a small category $\bf I$, the diagrams of shape $\bf I$ in a category $\bf C$ form a category, isomorphic to $\bf C^I$; also, one can think of the category of the diagrams of shape "opposed" to $\bf I$ as $\mathbf C^{(\mathbf I^{\mathrm {op}})}$. Plus one can  restrict to a subcategory $\bf D\subseteq  C^I$, e.g. stating that, for fixed $I\in \operatorname{ob}(\mathbf I),C\in \operatorname{ob}(\mathbf C)$, every $F\in \operatorname{ob}(\mathbf D)$ satisfies $F(I)=C$, and $f_I=\operatorname{id}_C$ for any $f\in \mathbf D(F,F')$; the same holds, obviously,  replacing $\mathbf I$ with $\mathbf I^{\operatorname{op}}$.

For instance, let $\bf I$ be the category $I_0\xrightarrow i I_1$, and consider the subcategory of $\bf C^I$ whose (object) functors send $I_1$ to a fixed $C\in \operatorname{ob} (C)$, and whose morphisms are the natural transformations with $\operatorname{id}_C$ as component at $I_1$;  such subcategory is clearly $\mathbf C/C$. On the other hand, $\mathbf I^{\operatorname{op}}$ is $I_1\to I_0$, and fixing that $I_1$ is sent to $C$, one now obtains $C/\bf C$ as a subcategory of $\mathbf C^{(\mathbf I^{\mathrm {op}})}$.

It is known that $\mathbf C^{\operatorname{op}}/C$ is dual to $C/\mathbf C$, but is it true that $(\mathbf C^{\operatorname{op}})^\mathbf I$ is dual to $\mathbf C^{(\mathbf I^{\mathrm {op}})}$ for a general $\bf I$? One can construct a contravariant functor $K:\mathbf C^{(\mathbf I^{\mathrm {op}})}\to (\mathbf C^{\operatorname{op}})^\mathbf I $, and an inverse (contravariant) functor $K^{-1}$ in the opposite direction, and I'd say that this already implies $((\mathbf C^{\operatorname{op}})^\mathbf I)^{\operatorname{op}}\cong \mathbf C^{(\mathbf I^{\mathrm {op}})}$. It's easy to see that $K$ is compatible with restrictions like that in the first paragraph, i.e. if $F:\mathbf  I^{\operatorname{op}}\to \mathbf C$ sends $I$ to $C$, the same can be said for $K(F):\mathbf  I\to \mathbf C^{\operatorname{op}}$, and analogously for natural transformation with a component that is the identity; thus this argument, if it is valid, should show also $(\mathbf C^{\operatorname{op}}/C)^{\operatorname{op}}\cong C/\mathbf C$, that was the exercise I was trying to solve ($1.2.\mathrm i$ in Riehl's book). Do you think that this solution is ok or you see any issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds good to me (assuming you wrote out the details for $K$.